# How to show PrintDialog in PrintPreviewDialog

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2012, print-preview, printdialog

I want to show PrintDialog (to choose the printer) when i click the button "Print" in the PrintPreviewDialog. I have add the code in the printdocument1_BeginPrint, but it did not work

```
private: System::Void printDocument1_BeginPrint(
    System::Object^ sender, 
    System::Drawing::Printing::PrintEventArgs^ e) 
{
    if (printDocument1->BeginPrint!=printDocument1->Print->PrintToPreview)
        printDialog1->ShowDialog();
}
```

I use visual studio 2012 C++ windows forms.

Comment: [`BeginPrint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.beginprint.aspx) seems to be an _event_. How does it make sense to compare it to something? Does this even compile?

Comment: non, i dont know how to do in fact. I have see this article but i dont know how to relise it in code.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b76af218-c462-4424-9350-3782514061af/combing-printpreviewdialog-and-printdialog?forum=Vsexpressvcs

Comment: answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40236241/how-to-add-print-dialog-to-the-printpreviewdialog