# How to add print dialog to the printpreviewdialog?

Tags: c#, printing, datagridview

My boss wants me to create the window form that has printing function, but he wants to print the `datagridview` after preview.

So now I encourage the problem, I cannot print multiple set of paper or choose the printer or make any changes when click the print button on `printpreviewdialog`.When I click the button, it will direct print the paper. So I wish to join the `printpreviewdialog` and `printdialog`.

Why the `printpreviewdialog` and `printdialog` can only be used in different buttons? It's lack of usibility when needed to click one button to preview and click another button to print multiple set and make changes of printer.

Any one can help me?

printdialog

```
DialogResult result = printDialog1.ShowDialog();
            // If the result is OK then print the document.
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                position = 0;
                pageno = 1;
                printDocument2.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(20, 20, 20, 20);
                printDocument2.OriginAtMargins = true;
                printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument2;
                printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
            }
```

printpreviewdialog

```
printDocument3.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(20, 20, 20, 20);
            printDocument3.OriginAtMargins = true;
            //((ToolStripButton)((ToolStrip)printPreviewDialog1.Controls[1]).Items[0]).Enabled = false;
            printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument3;
            printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what is your goal. You want to click start the printdialog and reflect all changes in that to the preview? So you start both windows at same time?

Comment: It is customary to select paper size and printer *before* you look at the preview.  Given that the preview is going to heavily depend on the paper size and printer capabilities.  Which is why PrintPreviewDialog doesn't have these buttons.  Use PrintPreviewControl to make your own custom dialog but do think this through for a bit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I know it is late, but i think someone will still need that.
As Hans Passant say, "print preview is heavily depended on printer and page settings."
But there is a print-button in printpreviewdialog, which is still reasonable for most cases. But that button directly prints to your default printer, and never shows a dialog.
If you want a print dialog from printpreview dialog, you can just manipulate ToolStrip of PrintPreviewDialog.

Here it goes (assuming you initialized printPreviewDialog1, printDialog1 and printDocument1 objects)

```
printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
ToolStripButton b = new ToolStripButton();
b.Image = Properties.Resources.PrintIcon;
b.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image;
b.Click += printPreview_PrintClick;
((ToolStrip)(printPreviewDialog1.Controls[1])).Items.RemoveAt(0);
((ToolStrip)(printPreviewDialog1.Controls[1])).Items.Insert(0, b);
printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

Using above code, you can remove default print button on ToolStrip of PrintPreview and replace it with a newly created "print button". This button now has an Click event handler, and by using it, you can show the PrintDialog.

```
private void printPreview_PrintClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDocument1.Print();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Only on client PC, When using `PrintPreviewDialog` it is showing the correct result, but when I try and print, the document content size is increased and gets trimmed by the paper (even if I try and print it to "Microsoft print to Pdf" printer)

Answer (score 9):

Works good...
Have one tip...
You can re-use the current icon by:

```
this.ToolStripButton.Image = ((System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip)(printPreviewDialog.Controls[1])).ImageList.Images[0];
```

The rest of the snippet:

```
        {
        this.ToolStripButton = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton();
        this.ToolStripButton.Image = ((System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip)(printPreviewDialog.Controls[1])).ImageList.Images[0];
        this.ToolStripButton.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image;
        this.ToolStripButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.printPreview_PrintClick);
        ((System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip)(printPreviewDialog.Controls[1])).Items.RemoveAt(0);
        ((System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip)(printPreviewDialog.Controls[1])).Items.Insert(0, ToolStripButton);
    }
    private void printPreview_PrintClick(object sender, System.EventArgs ee)
    {
        try
        {
            this.printDialog.Document = printDocument;
            if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                printDocument.Print();
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ToString());
        }
    }
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton ToolStripButton;
```

Answer (score 2):

The snippet provided by @AceIndy above, does not take into account if the user changes the default printer or its settings. This is how I solved that problem:

```
private void printPreview_PrintClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        printDialog.Document = printDocument;

        if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDocument.PrinterSettings = printDialog.PrinterSettings;

            printDocument.Print();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Stephen ... I'd like to have a chat about the markdown ...I think the markdown is unfair based on the premises all that was edited were my words "I hope this helps ... " ... particularly since those precise words are used in a plethora of answers in this site ...